# PyQGIS copy geometries between two layers causes commit error

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, qgsvectorlayer, add-feature

I have two `QgsVectorLayer`s, both POLYGON layers (no Z Values, no MULTIs etc.) and would like to copy some features from one of them to the others using PyQGIS (3.16 LTR) with the following code:

```
source_lyr = ...#some QgsVectorLayer
target_lyr = ...#some QgsVectorLayer
# not necessariliy the same crs
trans = QgsCoordinateTransform(source_lyr.crs(), target_lyr.crs(), QgsProject.instance())
fields = target_lyr.fields()
target_lyr.startEditing()
for f in source_lyr.getFeatures():
    new_feature = QgsFeature()
    new_feature.setFields(fields)
    new_geom = f.geometry()
    new_geom.transform(trans)
    new_feature.setGeometry(new_geom)
    target_lyr.addFeature(new_feature)
```

**Note** again: `...geometryType() == 2` for each layer.

Target layer switches to edit mode and the copied features appear in the map, but when I try to save layer changes I get a commit error *"Errors: ERROR: 5 feature(s) not added - geometry type is not compatible with the current layer."*:

[image]

Why is this? Why the heck is POLYGON not compatible with POLYGON?

Comment: What are the drivers/formats? Is `all([f.geometry().type() == target_lyr.geometryType() for f in source_lyr.getFeatures()])` true?

Comment: `all(...)` is `True`. source is dxf, target PostGIS in this case, but I intend to make it work with all drivers/formats.

Comment: @bugmenot123 It's dxf that causes the problems (quelle surprise...). Exported the dxf as gpkg and the issue vanishes. I do further investigation on this.

Comment: Gah, I am glad I don't touch dxf ever :) Maybe check the geometry types of all features after they were copied to `target_lyr` for discrepancies, if you're lucky they will differ then. Otherwise I'd say this is bug report worthy for being magic not working.

Comment: I had something familiar in pyqgis. In this case I made `.makeValid()` for a geometry object then burst a new object into lists of coordinates and create a new pure Polygon object. Somehow it did a thing.

Comment: Good idea! preserves me from saving the dxf to gpkg prior to use my script :-)